# How to control table row height with shifted content in cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to do a simple page with the following design:

[image]

The square in the first row is actually supposed to be something like this:

[image]

In order to do that, I'm creating a table to have the two columns and 3 rows and I wanted to create a div to draw the little square. I'm able to add the square there using:

```
 .squareClass{
    position: relative;
    top: -80px; 
    left: 20px;
 }
```

but the problem I'm having is that I don't kmow how to change the height of the first row (which is the height of the little square, even though it's moved up.

Any thoughts?

**edit:**

Here's the code for that:

```
<div class="container">
<table  border=1 style="width: 800px;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="squareClass" style="position: relative; top: -80px; left: 20px;">

            <div class="imageClass" style="float: left; border: 2px solid blue;"><img src="something.png" ></div>
            <divclass="infoClass" style="border: 2px solid yellow;"> 
                <div class="containerRightTop"> some text </div>
                <div class="containerRightBottom"> some other text </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="squareClass" style="position: relative; top: -80px; left: 20px;">

            <div class="imageClass" style="float: left; border: 2px solid blue;"><img src="something2.png" ></div>
            <div> 
                <div class="containerRightTop"> some text 2</div>
                <div class="containerRightBottom"> some other text 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td>cell21 content - just text</td><td>cell22 content- text</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is what I have:
[image: what I have]
Here is what I need:
[image]

So I'm not sure how to change the height of the table row to make it sort of align with the bottom of the image. I also don't know how to make the `containerRightBottom`show right below the top border of the table and the `containerRightTop` show right on top of the table.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkU8T/

Comment: so the square has a variable height?

Comment: not really. The image has a defined size. Also, the content of "containerRightBottom" is defined and static. So I also know the hight. And the bottom of "containerRightBottom" has to be aligned with the bottom of the image. And the top of "containerRightBottom" has to be touching the top of the table (container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured how to align both at the bottom by using this css:
And I can control the height by changing the squareClass height! Yay!

```
div.squareClass {
                position: relative;             
                width: 100%;
                height: 110px;
}
div.imageClass {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 45%;
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }

 div.infoClass {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 45%;
     border: 1px solid gray;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

can you show some more code? or try using this css:

```
 .squareClass{  float:left; width: 100px; height: 100px;  }
```

Comment: sorry I didn't add the full code before. I've just edited it to add more code and info.

Comment: BMF, can you please tell me your exact issue (via image) and which approach you want to go with like tables or DIVs.. ?

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this structure???

html::

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="first"></div>
        <div class="text"> 
            <div class="containerRightTop"> some text </div>
            <div class="containerRightBottom"> some other text</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="second"></div></td>
</tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

css ::

```
table{width:100%;position:absolute;top:30%;left:0;}
td{
width:50%;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
.first{
position:absolute;
top:-20%;
left:10%;
z-index:1000;
width:80px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
background:green;
}

.second{
position:absolute;
top:-20%;
left:70%;
z-index:1000;
width:80px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
background:green;
}
.text{
position:absolute;
top:-10%;
left:27%;
z-index:1000;
border:1px solid yellow;
background:white;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HSf7T/1/)**